# unwanted Icing mesh

Tags: mesh

no matter how many times I repeat the duplicate process (SHIFT+D, RIGHT-CLICK, P, SELECTION), I still get this unwanted mesh, and I've been stuck on this part more than I would like to admit. Is there something I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: What unwanted mesh? Post an image showing the collection outliner so that we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: it looks like you have selected 2 objects here: the donut and the icing. What are your trying to achieve? If you want to delete the icing object, just delete it with X. I'm not sure what you're trying to do when you duplicate...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if you zoom in a little more closely, you can see the highlighted orange mesh going through my icing. I'll post another photo to help clarify.

Comment: i went to edit mode to show what I really meant. like I have no idea how I keep getting a disfigured donut while in edit mode

Comment: That's how it's supposed to look! In your original image you'd obviously gone back into Object mode after separating the icing object because both meshes were selected. You should have then clicked on an empty part of the screen to deselect both meshes and then click back on just the icing section. That might need a couple of trys to select the right part. Your latest image shows that you've actually clicked on the donut itself and gone back into Edit mode rather than the icing Go back into Object mode and try clicking on the icing area so that just that is outlined in yellow and try again.

Comment: Incidentally the 'disfigured' part of your image is called 'Z-fighting' and occurs because both icing and donut are occupying exactly the same space. Blender then can't distinguish which is in front and tries to display both at once.